# Grouping items from mysql by the day they were posted

Tags: php, mysql, date, list, group-by

So, I'm having a problem building a feed-style list of posts efficiently using PHP and Mysql.
I want to output the posts organized and grouped by the day they were posted, showing the date as a header. For example:

```
February 9th -----------

Posts that were posted on Feb 9th

Feb 8th -----------------

Posts that were posted on the 8th
```

Hopefully that is clear. I'll try to clear up things if someone is confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag in the question hints at using "GROUP BY". You do *not* need the SQL GROUP BY construct.  Instead, the query should look something like :

```
SELECT *
FROM MyPostsTable
--WHERE  some optional condition
ORDER BY PostingDate -- DESC  (if you want the newer dates first)
```

Then as you iterate through the resuults list, in PHP, you simply need to keep tabs of the date of the items currently being output, and emit a header of sort ("February 9th ----------"), at the start of a new date.

**Edit**: see Matt Bridges' answer for a sample implementation of the logic described above.

Comment: This was the method I ended up using. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please post the code you use??? Am trying to figure this out and it's driving me insane! :(

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT PostDataColumn1, PostDataColumn2, date_format('%Y-%m-%d', DateColumn) FROM posts_table ORDER BY DateColumn DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$curDate = "";    

while (list($col1, $col2, $date) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  if ($date != $curDate)
  {
    echo "$date --------\n";
    $curDate = $date;
  }

  echo "Post data: $col1 $col2";
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing the PHP code, rather than just explaining its general logic as I did ;-)